# The inverse image of an open ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $\phi:D\to\mathbb{R}^n$, where $D$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $\phi^{-1}(\{p\})=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$. Suppose $\exists r>0$ s.t. $B(a_i,r)$'s are pairwise disjoint open balls. Is it possible to find $\epsilon>0$ s.t.
>   $$\phi^{-1}(B(p,\epsilon))\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^3 B(a_i,r)?$$
>   Thank you very much.

In fact, I would like to prove that $\exists\epsilon_2>0$ s.t.
$$\phi^{-1}(B(p,\epsilon_2))\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^k B(a_i,r).$$

[image]
[image]
[image]

> $Z_\phi$ is the set of all crical points. For simplicity, you can consider both $Q$ and $B$ to be open balls.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $\phi$?

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Comment: "Degree Theory in Analysis and Applications" by Gangbo Fonseca, Irene Fonseca, Wilfrid Gangbo

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you mean $\phi$ continuous; I don't think it's possible.

To give you a visual counterexample,

[image]

this is $D = (0,1)\times(0,1)$. Notice that **it doesn't include the borders**.

[image]

This is $R^2$, with your point $p$.

Now, I'll fold $D$ and map it to $R^2$ in this way:

[image]

[image]

If we check the counterimage if $p$, we can see $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$. But if we instead check the counterimage of any neighborhood of $p$, it's clear that not only we'll have the neighborhoods of $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$ **but also one near the border**.

[image]

I was able to do this trick because $D$ is not compact; I don't know if it's possible otherwise.

I hope this is somewhat clear.

Comment: Not clear and though it is mathematical,  it is not mathematics.

Comment: Thank you. I posted the entire problem.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For example with n = 1,
map the three points a,b,c to p, and for all integers k > 0, map a + k to a + 1/k
and every thing else to a point other than a, b, or c.

Comment: Thank you. Please see the update.